# Perl - convert ASCII art to use x operator

Tags: perl, run-length-encoding

I would like to convert ASCII art to something that takes less bytes. I have string like this:

```
my $string = '                ██   ████   █';
```

And I would convert this to something like this:

```
print "█" x 1."█" x 1."█" x 1"█" x 1"█" x 1;
```

So I would write this in one line and convert to using `x` operator. How can achieve this?

Comment: `1"` is a syntax error.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).  Also, StackOverflow questions should only contain one question, not multiple.  You might consider moving your second question to a separate post.

Comment: You might find certain posts on [codegolf.se] very helpful.

Comment: Essentially you want to analyse the string, count how often each character is there, and then repeat it `n` times. That's on the level of an exercise from the _Learning Perl_ book I would say.

Comment: I'd go with an existing zip library instead of implementing my own compressor/encoder...

Answer (score 0):

```
print '                ██   ████   █' x 1;
```

Personally, I'd only meet one of your requirements.

Single-line:

```
print '                ██   ████   █';
```

Using `x`:

```
print(
   ' ' x 16, '█' x  2,
   ' ' x  3, '█' x  4,
   ' ' x  3, '█' x  1,
);
```